# Python Lifetimes Module Error

Tags: python, python-2.7, lifetime-scoping

I was trying to load the Lifetimes Module on my Linux AMI server.
I installed it just fine and everything seemed to work with no error.

However when I went to use it I got the error below. (tried to do a few things that I thought would fix it but nothing has worked)

```
import lifetimes
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "lifetimes/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .estimation import BetaGeoFitter, ParetoNBDFitter, GammaGammaFitter
  File "lifetimes/estimation.py", line 2, in <module>
    from collections import OrderedDict
ImportError: cannot import name OrderedDict
```

Comment: Did you install as the `root` user or in your `$HOME` directory as an unprivileged user?

Comment: Run `python -V`. Make *sure* you're running on Python 2.7. This is the error message you'd get on Python 2.6 or previous.

Comment: You are right that I am running python 2.6.  Thank you

Comment: It seems I have both 2.7 and 2.6 installed.  I thought I was running 2.7 but apparently not

Answer (score 0):

http://linuxconfig.org/how-to-change-from-default-to-alternative-python-version-on-debian-linux

This is what worked for me but I did have to re-install the modules that were on 2.6 into 2.7